# How to set more cameras into different multiple image reference?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode, camera, image

I'll explain it short, How does This work like if I want add different image on cam 2, but I don't want have same image from cam 1?[image]

Answer (score 0):

you first should change from your source from single image to image sequence.

[image]

Then just open your first image file.

And adapt the correct number of frames.

Repeat this for the second camera.

[image]